# Fix an arrow in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I'm using chemfig to write a reaction of sucrose degradation, but the first arrow is too near the `+` sign. I tried using `\indent` but it didn't work.

```
\definesubmol{x}{(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)}
\definesubmol{y}{(-[0]H)(-[4]HO)}

\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-(-[0]OH)=(-[3]H)-[1]OH}}{1, 2 Enediol}
    \arrow
    \indent \indent \indent \+
    \arrow(--tri){0}[90,0.15]
    \indent \indent \indent \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-(-[0]OH)=(-[3]H)-[1]OH}}{Triosa Enediol}
    \arrow(--gli){0}[-90,0.30]
    \indent \indent \indent \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Gliceraldehído}
        \arrow(--met)
        \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_3-(=[0]O)-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{Metilglioxal}
        \arrow(@tri.mid east--@met)[-45]
        \arrow
        \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_3-!x-(-[3]HO)=[1]O}}{D-Ácido Láctico}
        \arrow(@tri--){<=>}
        \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-(=[0]O)-CH_2 \cdot OH}}{Dihidroxiacetona}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inserting `\hspace{5mm}` or something like this?

Comment: No. It worked pretty well, by adding 7 mm to both molecules and 5 mm to the + sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: In order to add horizontal space, you can use the `\hspace` command right after the `+`. E.g. `+\hspace{7mm}`.